# Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client, google-my-business-api

I have a console app written with `C#` on the top of .NET Core 2.2 framework.

I am trying to use my app to connect Google My Business API to create [posts](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/posts-data).

But every time I try to call the REST API I get the following error

> Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2
>   access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
>   See
>   https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

The code worked previously, but for some odd reason, it stopped!

Hereis an example where I get authentication token and then call the API to get a list of [Google accounts](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/account-data).

```
var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
{
    ClientId = "Client ID",
    ClientSecret = "Client Secret",
}, new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage" }, "google username", CancellationToken.None);

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{   
    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", credential.Token.AccessToken);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var c = await client.GetAsync("https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts");
    var accountContentss = await c.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    c.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var accountContent = await c.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

I am able to authenticate and get the access token with no issue. However, the second call to the API fails for some reason.

How can I correctly call Google API? Beside the AccesToken, is there something else that should get passed in the header?

Answer (score 5):

It turned out to be that `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()` was returning an expired token! It would have been very helpful if the API returned a message stating that the token is expired instead!

To fix the issue, instead of accessing the `AccessToken` manually (i.e, `credential.Token.AccessToken`), I used `await Credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync()` method to get an access token.

The `Credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync()` method returns an valid token any time it is called. In other words, if the token is expired, it uses the refresh-token to generate a new one. Otherwise, it return the existing non-expired token.

I change my Authorization header to this

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", await Credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync());
```